# how to save the best tree after 10 fold cross validation on J48 / C4.5 using Weka API

Tags: java, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, weka, decision-tree

hope everyone is in the best of health.

I want to do 10 fold cross validation on a set of data, using J48 as the classifier. So the data is loaded, then i want to create training and test sets using 10 fold cross validation, and after 10 trees are generated i want to save the tree with the best classification accuracy and  use that as the rule base.

So far my program loads the data, does 10 fold cross validation and then Ive tired to save the classifier. However am not sure if i am on the right track as i want to save the best tree out of the 10, and also save the rules.

How can i do this ?

Also where would i create test sets ? is my program doing the split correctly ?

Thank you for any advice and help.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Random;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.Range;

public class Unpruned {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    try
    {


            BufferedReader bReader = readDataFile("weather.arrf");
            Instances train = new Instances(bReader);
            train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() -1); //last attribute is the class attribute

            J48 myTree = new J48();
            myTree.setUnpruned(true);

            Evaluation eval=new Evaluation(train);
             //first supply the classifier
             //then the training data
             //number of folds
             //random seed
             eval.crossValidateModel(myTree, train, 10, new Random(1));
             System.out.println("Percent correct: "+
                                Double.toString(eval.pctCorrect()));

             myTree.buildClassifier(train);
             System.out.print(myTree.graph());

             weka.core.SerializationHelper.write("D:/myTree.model", myTree);

    }catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }   
}



public static BufferedReader readDataFile(String filename) {
BufferedReader inputReader = null;

try {
    inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.err.println("File not found: " + filename);
}

return inputReader;
}

}
```

**UPDATE :**

@matthew spencer

ok i have changed my program to this know, so in the output i get 10 trees, and it gives me the rules for each one. How would i go about saving just one, e.g fold 9.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.evaluation.NominalPrediction;
import weka.classifiers.rules.DecisionTable;
import weka.classifiers.rules.PART;
import weka.classifiers.trees.DecisionStump;
import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
import weka.core.FastVector;
import weka.core.Instances;

public class WekaTest {
public static BufferedReader readDataFile(String filename) {
    BufferedReader inputReader = null;

    try {
        inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("File not found: " + filename);
    }

    return inputReader;
}

public static Evaluation classify(Classifier model,
        Instances trainingSet, Instances testingSet) throws Exception {
    Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(trainingSet);

    model.buildClassifier(trainingSet);
    evaluation.evaluateModel(model, testingSet);

    return evaluation;
}

public static double calculateAccuracy(FastVector predictions) {
    double correct = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < predictions.size(); i++) {
        NominalPrediction np = (NominalPrediction) predictions.elementAt(i);
        if (np.predicted() == np.actual()) {
            correct++;
        }
    }

    return 100 * correct / predictions.size();
}

public static Instances[][] crossValidationSplit(Instances data, int numberOfFolds) {
    Instances[][] split = new Instances[2][numberOfFolds];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFolds; i++) {
        split[0][i] = data.trainCV(numberOfFolds, i);
        split[1][i] = data.testCV(numberOfFolds, i);
    }

    return split;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader datafile = readDataFile("pima_diabetes.arrf");

    Instances data = new Instances(datafile);
    data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

    // Do 10-split cross validation
    Instances[][] split = crossValidationSplit(data, 10);

    // Separate split into training and testing arrays
    Instances[] trainingSplits = split[0];
    Instances[] testingSplits = split[1];

    // Use a set of classifiers
    Classifier[] models = { 
            new J48(), // a decision tree
            new PART(), 
            new DecisionTable(),//decision table majority classifier
            new DecisionStump() //one-level decision tree
    };

    // Run for each model
    for (int j = 0; j < models.length; j++) {

        // Collect every group of predictions for current model in a FastVector
        FastVector predictions = new FastVector();

        // For each training-testing split pair, train and test the classifier
        for (int i = 0; i < trainingSplits.length; i++) {
            Evaluation validation = classify(models[j], trainingSplits[i], testingSplits[i]);

            predictions.appendElements(validation.predictions());

            // Uncomment to see the summary for each training-testing pair.
            System.out.println(models[j].toString());
        }

        // Calculate overall accuracy of current classifier on all splits
        double accuracy = calculateAccuracy(predictions);

        // Print current classifier's name and accuracy in a complicated,
        // but nice-looking way.
        System.out.println("Accuracy of " + models[j].getClass().getSimpleName() + ": "
                + String.format("%.2f%%", accuracy)
                + "\n---------------------------------" + models[1].toString() );
    }

}
```

}

**UPDATE 2:**

my output :

```
Accuracy of J48: 74.87%
---------------------------------J48 pruned tree
------------------

    plas <= 127: tested_negative (437.0/85.0)
    plas > 127
    |   mass <= 29.9: tested_negative (70.0/20.0)
    |   mass > 29.9
    |   |   pres <= 61: tested_positive (22.0)
    |   |   pres > 61
    |   |   |   plas <= 157
    |   |   |   |   age <= 30
    |   |   |   |   |   preg <= 0
    |   |   |   |   |   |   pres <= 68: tested_positive (4.0)
    |   |   |   |   |   |   pres > 68
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   insu <= 135
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   mass <= 35.5: tested_negative (3.0)
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   mass > 35.5: tested_positive (4.0/1.0)
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   insu > 135: tested_negative (2.0)
    |   |   |   |   |   preg > 0
    |   |   |   |   |   |   preg <= 2: tested_negative (11.0)
    |   |   |   |   |   |   preg > 2
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   pedi <= 0.332: tested_negative (6.0)
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   pedi > 0.332
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   plas <= 144: tested_positive (4.0)
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   plas > 144: tested_negative (3.0)
    |   |   |   |   age > 30: tested_positive (52.0/15.0)
    |   |   |   plas > 157: tested_positive (74.0/11.0)

Number of Leaves  :     13

Size of the tree :  25

Accuracy of PART: 72.40%
---------------------------------J48 pruned tree
------------------

    plas <= 127: tested_negative (437.0/85.0)
    plas > 127
    |   mass <= 29.9: tested_negative (70.0/20.0)
    |   mass > 29.9
    |   |   pres <= 61: tested_positive (22.0)
    |   |   pres > 61
    |   |   |   plas <= 157
    |   |   |   |   age <= 30
    |   |   |   |   |   preg <= 0
    |   |   |   |   |   |   pres <= 68: tested_positive (4.0)
    |   |   |   |   |   |   pres > 68
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   insu <= 135
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   mass <= 35.5: tested_negative (3.0)
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   mass > 35.5: tested_positive (4.0/1.0)
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   insu > 135: tested_negative (2.0)
    |   |   |   |   |   preg > 0
    |   |   |   |   |   |   preg <= 2: tested_negative (11.0)
    |   |   |   |   |   |   preg > 2
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   pedi <= 0.332: tested_negative (6.0)
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   pedi > 0.332
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   plas <= 144: tested_positive (4.0)
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   plas > 144: tested_negative (3.0)
    |   |   |   |   age > 30: tested_positive (52.0/15.0)
    |   |   |   plas > 157: tested_positive (74.0/11.0)

Number of Leaves  :     13

Size of the tree :  25

Accuracy of DecisionTable: 73.96%
---------------------------------J48 pruned tree
------------------

plas <= 127: tested_negative (437.0/85.0)
plas > 127
|   mass <= 29.9: tested_negative (70.0/20.0)
|   mass > 29.9
|   |   pres <= 61: tested_positive (22.0)
|   |   pres > 61
|   |   |   plas <= 157
|   |   |   |   age <= 30
|   |   |   |   |   preg <= 0
|   |   |   |   |   |   pres <= 68: tested_positive (4.0)
|   |   |   |   |   |   pres > 68
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   insu <= 135
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   mass <= 35.5: tested_negative (3.0)
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   mass > 35.5: tested_positive (4.0/1.0)
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   insu > 135: tested_negative (2.0)
|   |   |   |   |   preg > 0
|   |   |   |   |   |   preg <= 2: tested_negative (11.0)
|   |   |   |   |   |   preg > 2
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   pedi <= 0.332: tested_negative (6.0)
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   pedi > 0.332
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   plas <= 144: tested_positive (4.0)
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   plas > 144: tested_negative (3.0)
|   |   |   |   age > 30: tested_positive (52.0/15.0)
|   |   |   plas > 157: tested_positive (74.0/11.0)

Number of Leaves  :     13

Size of the tree :  25

Accuracy of DecisionStump: 72.01%
---------------------------------J48 pruned tree
------------------

plas <= 127: tested_negative (437.0/85.0)
plas > 127
|   mass <= 29.9: tested_negative (70.0/20.0)
|   mass > 29.9
|   |   pres <= 61: tested_positive (22.0)
|   |   pres > 61
|   |   |   plas <= 157
|   |   |   |   age <= 30
|   |   |   |   |   preg <= 0
|   |   |   |   |   |   pres <= 68: tested_positive (4.0)
|   |   |   |   |   |   pres > 68
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   insu <= 135
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   mass <= 35.5: tested_negative (3.0)
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   mass > 35.5: tested_positive (4.0/1.0)
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   insu > 135: tested_negative (2.0)
|   |   |   |   |   preg > 0
|   |   |   |   |   |   preg <= 2: tested_negative (11.0)
|   |   |   |   |   |   preg > 2
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   pedi <= 0.332: tested_negative (6.0)
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   pedi > 0.332
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   plas <= 144: tested_positive (4.0)
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   plas > 144: tested_negative (3.0)
|   |   |   |   age > 30: tested_positive (52.0/15.0)
|   |   |   plas > 157: tested_positive (74.0/11.0)

Number of Leaves  :     13

Size of the tree :  25
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are well too!

I have had a look [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html) and could not find any clear indications of access to individual classifiers from the Evaluation Class.  I also ran a test sample using 10-fold cross-validation for J48 and there appeared to be no clear access to individual classifiers either.

If you need to find the best of the ten, perhaps you could programmatically generate the 10 folds and use the Training and Evaluation algorithms that you have applied above, then save the classifier that gave the best results in the end.

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE!**

Based on the changes above, please find below one possible solution for selecting and saving the best classifier:

```
// Run for each model
Classifier bestClassifier = models[0];
double bestAccuracy = -1;

for (int j = 0; j < models.length; j++) {

    // Collect every group of predictions for current model in a FastVector
    FastVector predictions = new FastVector();

    // For each training-testing split pair, train and test the classifier
    for (int i = 0; i < trainingSplits.length; i++) {
        Evaluation validation = classify(models[j], trainingSplits[i], testingSplits[i]);
        predictions.appendElements(validation.predictions());
    }

    // Calculate overall accuracy of current classifier on all splits
    double accuracy = calculateAccuracy(predictions);

    if (accuracy > bestAccuracy)
    {
        bestClassifier = models[j];
        bestAccuracy = accuracy;
    }

    // Print current classifier's name and accuracy in a complicated,
    // but nice-looking way.
    System.out.println("Accuracy of " + models[j].getClass().getSimpleName() + ": "
            + String.format("%.2f%%", accuracy));
}

// Save the Best Classifier
 weka.core.SerializationHelper.write("best.model", bestClassifier);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. What am essentially trying to do is find the best fold out of the ten and then save the rules of that tree to later create a Fuzzy Decision Tree. 

I dont quite understand what you mean by programmatically generate 10 folds, would you mind explaining a bit further ?

Regards

Comment: What I was thinking was that if you couldn't get a single classifier from each of the folds, perhaps you could generate the ten different folds and then generate the classifiers individually, then save the most accurate classifier from there.

Comment: please look at my first post, i have put an update there , thanks

Comment: I have added a potential solution according to your amendments.

Comment: thanks alot for that @matthew. I also added a bestClassifier.toString() in the println so i can see the output of each classifer, so i have put my output above in my first post, so now i save these rules and build a tree with them can i somehow save it in a array or something ? If there is a way how would it know the start and end of a rule ? Is parsing possible or do i have to hard code it ?

regards

Comment: When you mean save into an array, do you mean get all of the rules into an array?  I'm not sure, but [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable/3.6.6/weka/classifiers/trees/j48/ClassifierTree.java#ClassifierTree.toString%28%29) may help identify how the rules are obtained and printed out.